# Trigger Google Maps Marker Outside Map

Tags: jquery, google-maps

How do I trigger the "infoWindow" when I click on an element outside of the map?

I have this:

```
var locations = [
  ['Location 1', 59.917224,10.587052, 1],
  ['Location 2', 59.912665,10.726153, 2]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 9,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.913869,10.752245),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

And having a HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>Trigger Marker 1</li>
<li>Trigger Marker 1</li>
</ul>
```

Any good ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Made an update of the code here:

var locations = [
  ['Location 1', 59.917224,10.587052, 1],
  ['Location 2', 59.912665,10.726153, 2]
];

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 9,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.913869,10.752245),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

var markerMap = {}

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  markerMap[ "marker-" + i ] = marker  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

 $(".marker-list").on('click', function() {
 var id = $(this).find('li').attr( 'data-id' );
 alert(id)
 infoWindow.open( map, markerMap[ id ] );
 }); 

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="marker-list">
<li data-id="marker-1">Trigger Marker 1</li>
<li data-id="marker-2">Trigger Marker 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put markers to the object with any id field inside loop eg:

```
//before loop declare object
var markerMap = {}
...
//inside loop add marker to object with uuid (e.g mareker-1)
markerMap[ "marker-" + i ] = marker
```

Then add the same id param to you HTML markup

```
<ul class="marker-list">
   <li data-id="marker-1">Trigger Marker 1</li>
   <li data-id="marker-2">Trigger Marker 2</li>
</ul>
```

and finally add event to li element (e.g using jQuery)

```
 $(".marker-list").click( function() {
     var id = $(this).attr( 'data-id' );
     infoWindow.open( map, markerMap[ id ] );
 });
```

I didnt test this code. Its jsut an idea. I hope you know what i have in my mind

Comment: Thanks Pawel! I get your idea! But I couldn't get it to work anyway, But I made an update above, can you see anything there that could be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this update to your code:

```
markerMap[ "marker-" + i ] = marker
```

This should open the infowindow on "marker-1":

```
google.maps.event.trigger(markerMap["marker-1"], "click");
```

Answer (score 0):

Save each of the marker in an array and then on the li click just use the corresponing marker from the array

```
var markers = [];
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  markers[i] = marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```